# Notifications every day for a particular date range

Tags: flutter

So, I have an app where users are reminded to take medicines every day at a particular time for a certain interval of dates. For example, the user can choose to get a notification from September 16,2020 to September 18,2020 at some time of the day

My approach : I schedule a notification using the `flutter_local_notifications` package with `showDailyAtTime()` function. However, the problem I face is that, suppose I don't open the app again, there is no way to cancel the scheduled notification and thus, the notification pops up even after the specified date range. I would like the notifications to be offline, so Firebase doesn't seem to be an option.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem with [FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications).

The approach would be to call the method `rescheduleNotifications` every time you start the app. In the method all notifications are removed and the next notifications are set. In `calculateNotificationTimes` for example you calculate all notifications for the next 30 days. For example, all notifications on September 16, 2020 to September 18, 2020 each day at a time of your choice.

```dart
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';

Future<void> rescheduleNotifications() async {
  final localNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  const initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(AndroidInitializationSettings('app_icon'), IOSInitializationSettings());
  const androidChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails('your channel id', 'your channel name', 'your channel description');
  const iOSNotificationDetails = IOSNotificationDetails();
  const notificationsDetails = NotificationDetails(androidChannelSpecifics, iOSNotificationDetails);

  await localNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);
  await localNotificationsPlugin.cancelAll();

  // Calculate the next notifications.
  final notificationTimes = calculateNotificationTimes();

  var _currentNotificationId = 0;
  for (final time in notificationTimes) {
    localNotificationsPlugin.schedule(
      _currentNotificationId++,
      "It's time to take your medicine.",
      'Take the red pill',
      time,
      notificationsDetails,
      androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
    );
  }
}
```

On iOS there is a limit that you can only have 64 notifications enabled. The disadvantage of this method on iOS is that if the user does not open the app after 64 notifications, no notification will be displayed. Which is fine, I think, because it seems that the user does not use the app anymore.

Did not test the code.

Comment: With this, the notification wouldn't come up everyday unless I open the app right? Also, even the cancellation happens only if I open the app. This I think brings back the same problem

Comment: With this method the notifications could be displayed every day. To do this, the 'calculateNotificationTimes' method would only need to output one time for each day. This has the advantage over showDailyAtTime that no unnecessary notifications can be displayed.